# Auto paste clipboard contents when emacs *scratch* buffer opens

Tags: emacs, clipboard

Most of the time when I open emacs without arguments it's to manipulate the clipboard contents.
So I would like emacs to start and display directly the clipboard contents in the *scratch* buffer that opens.

Answer (score 1):

I added this to my .emacs, seems to do the job :

```
;; Opening *scratch* with clipboard contents (if clipboard contains text)
(condition-case nil
    (setq initial-scratch-message (clipboard-yank))
    (error (setq initial-scratch-message nil))
)
```

NB : Since the *scratch* buffer will always open with the clipboard text, you might also want to change default major mode for *scratch* buffer to text

```
;; Defaulting *scratch* buffer to text-mode
(setq initial-major-mode 'text-mode)
```

I finally also added this to perform same clipboard paste when I open an empty .txt file

```
;; Opening empty txt files with clipboard contents (if clipboard contains text)
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'paste-clipboard-for-empty-txt-files)
(defun paste-clipboard-for-empty-txt-files ()
  (when (and (string= (file-name-extension buffer-file-name) "txt")
                      (= (buffer-size) 0))
    (condition-case nil (clipboard-yank) (error nil))))
```